# Activating applet on a JavaCard

Tags: nfc, smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

I am using an TRF7970A trasciver combined with a MCU to try to get some information from a Java Card Applet. The problem I run into is that I managed to exchange information with the tag up to the Applet Activation command. That means I manage to do the anticollison procedure, select command, rats command, but when i get to activating the applet I get no answer, not even an error. The exact command secquence that I am sending from the device to the tag, I have tested it with an NFC debbugger and works ok. So it seems there is something with the applet activation command. Can someone indicate me a probable cause or a solution?
The command I am sending is: 0x02 0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0x09 <9bytes the Applet ID>, I have also tried with 0x0A 0x00 0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0x09  and still nothing.
The communication medium protocol is ISO14443 Type A, and IsoDep (which is the one I use to activate the applet).

Sry for not posting also the code. Here are the used functions:

1.This functions searches for a tag and retrives the information from it:

```
    void NFC_TagSearch(uint8_t interface, uint8_t *state, uint8_t *RetrieTimer, uint8_t side)
        {
        Iso14443a_halt(interface, &gNFC[side]);if(*state==RF_1356_START_TAGSEARCH)
        {
    Iso14443aAnticollisionInitiate(0x01, iHFRF, &gNFC[side]);
    *RetrieTimer=1;
    while(*RetrieTimer <= RF_1356_WAIT_AFTER_COMMAND && gNFC[side].Status!=0xFF && gNFC[side].Status!=0x02){}
    if(*RetrieTimer <= RF_1356_WAIT_AFTER_COMMAND)
    {
        char c[6];
        hex2str(gNFC[side].Status,c,1);
        USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)c,4,DEBUG_MSG);
        USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)"->",2,DEBUG_MSG);
        uint8_t i=0;
        for(i=0;i<gNFC[side].Size;i++)
        {
            hex2str(gNFC[side].Data[i],c,1);
            USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)&c[2],2,DEBUG_MSG);
        }
        USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)"\r\n",2,DEBUG_MSG);
        USART_TransmitBuffers(iDEBUG);
     }
     else
     {
        USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)"Time\r\n",6,DEBUG_MSG);
        USART_TransmitBuffers(iDEBUG);
     }
    *RetrieTimer=0;
    if(gNFC[side].Status==0xFF || gNFC[side].Status==0x02)
    {
        memset(gNFC[side].uid,0x00,10);
        if(Iso14443aAnticolissionLoop(iHFRF, &gNFC[side]))
        {
            /*We got and UID go to RATS*/
            TRF7970A_CRC_ON(interface);
            *state=RF_1356_WAITRATSANSWER;
            Iso14443a_RATS(interface,&gNFC[side]);
            *RetrieTimer=1;
            while(*RetrieTimer <= RF_1356_WAIT_AFTER_COMMAND && gNFC[side].Status!=0xFF){}
             if(*RetrieTimer <= RF_1356_WAIT_AFTER_COMMAND)
             {
                char c[6];
                hex2str(gNFC[side].Status,c,1);
                USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)c,4,DEBUG_MSG);
                USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)"->",2,DEBUG_MSG);
                uint8_t i=0;
                for(i=0;i<gNFC[side].Size;i++)
                {
                    hex2str(gNFC[side].Data[i],c,1);
                    USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)&c[2],2,DEBUG_MSG);
                }
                USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)"\r\n",2,DEBUG_MSG);
                USART_TransmitBuffers(iDEBUG);
             }
             else
             {
                USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)"Time\r\n",6,DEBUG_MSG);
                USART_TransmitBuffers(iDEBUG);
             }
            *RetrieTimer=0;
            if((*RetrieTimer >= RF_1356_WAIT_AFTER_COMMAND) || (gNFC[side].Status==0xFF))
                {
                    if((gNFC[side].Data[0]) == 0x05)
                        {
                        /*Command for activation of the applet*/
                         Iso14443a_ActivateApplet(interface,&gNFC[side]);
                        *RetrieTimer=1;
                         while(*RetrieTimer <= RF_1356_WAIT_AFTER_COMMAND && gNFC[side].Status!=0xFF){}
                         if(gNFC[0].Size>0/**RetrieTimer <= RF_1356_WAIT_AFTER_COMMAND*/)
                         {
                            char c[6];
                            hex2str(gNFC[0].Status,c,1);
                            USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)c,4,DEBUG_MSG);
                            USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)"->",2,DEBUG_MSG);
                            uint8_t i=0;
                            for(i=0;i<gNFC[0].Size;i++)
                            {
                                hex2str(gNFC[0].Data[i],c,1);
                                USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)&c[2],2,DEBUG_MSG);
                            }
                            USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)"\r\n",2,DEBUG_MSG);
                            USART_TransmitBuffers(iDEBUG);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                            USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)"Timeout\r\n",9,DEBUG_MSG);
                            USART_TransmitBuffers(iDEBUG);
                         }
                         if(gNFC[1].Size>0/**RetrieTimer <= RF_1356_WAIT_AFTER_COMMAND*/)
                         {
                            char c[6];
                            hex2str(gNFC[1].Status,c,1);
                            USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)c,4,DEBUG_MSG);
                            USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)"->",2,DEBUG_MSG);
                            uint8_t i=0;
                            for(i=0;i<gNFC[1].Size;i++)
                            {
                                hex2str(gNFC[1].Data[i],c,1);
                                USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)&c[2],2,DEBUG_MSG);
                            }
                            USART_AddBuffer(iDEBUG,(uint8_t *)"\r\n",2,DEBUG_MSG);
                            USART_TransmitBuffers(iDEBUG);
                        }
                        *RetrieTimer=0;
                        if(gNFC[side].Status==0xFF)
                        {
                                    if((gNFC[side].Data[0]) == 0x90 && (gNFC[side].Data[1]) == 0x00)
                                    {
                                    /*Command for activation of the applet*/
                                        *state=RF_1356_START_TAGSEARCH;
                                        *RetrieTimer=0;
                                        gDevice.DeviceState=(/*DEVICE_STATE_WAIT_CARD*/0x01==gDevice.DeviceState)?(/*DEVICE_STATE_GOT_CARD*/0x04):(gDevice.DeviceState);
                                    }
                                    else
                                        *state=RF_1356_START_TAGSEARCH;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        /*Go back and send command again*/
                                *state=RF_1356_START_TAGSEARCH;
                         }
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        /*Go back and send command again*/
                        *state=RF_1356_START_TAGSEARCH;
                    }
                }
            else
            {
                /*Go back and send command again*/
                *state=RF_1356_START_TAGSEARCH;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /*Go back and send command again*/
            *state=RF_1356_START_TAGSEARCH;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /*Go back and send command again*/
        *state=RF_1356_START_TAGSEARCH;
    }
        }
        Iso14443a_halt(interface, &gNFC[side]);
        Delay_ms(500);
        LL_IWDG_ReloadCounter(IWDG);
    }
```

2.Everithing works until the Applect Activation function for which command i get no answer, this is the functions:

```
    void Iso14443a_ActivateApplet(uint8_t interface,__NFCInterfaces *NFC)
    {
        /*Tried also to reconfigure the chip, just in case*/
        trf7970a_write_single(interface,TRF7970A_ISO_CTRL, TRF7970A_ISO_CTRL_14443A_106);
        TRF7970A_CRC_ON(interface);
        uint8_t length;
        uint8_t buf[50];
        NFC->CorruptedResponse=0;
        NFC->Size=0;
        NFC->Status=0x00;
        length=0;
        buf[length++] = 0x00;   /*Length of the packet to be sent, this value is for the TRF7970A chip*/
        buf[length++] = 0x00;   /*Length of the packet to be sent, this value is for the TRF7970A chip*/
        /*The sent packet*/
        buf[length++] = 0x00;
        buf[length++] = 0xA4;
        buf[length++] = 0x04;
        buf[length++] = 0x00;
        buf[length++] = 0x09; //0x09
        buf[length++] = 0xC2; //<-AID
        buf[length++] = 0xB6;
        buf[length++] = 0xCA;
        buf[length++] = 0x27;
        buf[length++] = 0xA1;
        buf[length++] = 0x93;
        buf[length++] = 0x1B;
        buf[length++] = 0x14;
        buf[length++] = 0x1D;
        /*The sent packet*/
        buf[0]=((length-2)>>4)&0x0F; /*Add the length high nibble to the buffer*/
        buf[1]=((length-2)<<4)&0xF0; /*Add the length low nibble to the buffer*/
        trf7970a_sendToTag(interface, 1, buf, length);
        /*Tested commands*/
        //02 00    A4040009 C2B6CA27A1931B141D
        //0A 00 00 A4040000 C2B6CA27A1931B141D
        //0A 00 00 A4040009 C2B6CA27A1931B141D
        //0A0000A404000B4A617661436172644F530100/*CID present and 0*/
        //0200A404000B4A617661436172644F530100/*CID not present*/
    }
```

3.And this are the functions used in the ActivateApplet function:

```
    uint8_t trf7970a_sendToTag(uint8_t interface, uint8_t crc, uint8_t *buf, uint8_t len)
    {
    /*Clear the chip FIFO buffer*/
        trf7970a_command(interface, TRF7970A_CMD_FIFO_RESET);
    /*Send command with or without crc*/
        (crc)?(trf7970a_command(interface, TRF7970A_CMD_TRANSMIT)):(trf7970a_command(interface, TRF7970A_CMD_TRANSMIT_NO_CRC));
    /*Send data to buffer starting from the length registers and then continuing with the FIFO buffer, first 2 bytes in buffer are the legth of data to be sent by the chip*/
        trf7970a_write_continous(interface, TRF7970A_TX_LENGTH_BYTE1, buf,len);
        return 1;
    }
```

The functions used like trf7970a_write_continous, trf7970a_command, trf7970a_write_single and TRF7970A_CRC_ON I am sure they work cause I used them in other commands.
Also the chip configuration function is:

```
    void trf7970a_init(uint8_t interface)
    {
        HFRF_ENABLECHIP;
        Delay_ms(500);
        trf7970a_command(interface, TRF7970A_CMD_SOFT_INIT);
        trf7970a_command(interface, TRF7970A_CMD_IDLE);
        uint8_t sysclkval=0x00;
        trf7970a_write_single(interface, TRF7970A_MODULATOR_SYS_CLK_CTRL, sysclkval);
        uint8_t regio=0x00 | TRF7970A_REG_IO_CTRL_VRS(7);
        trf7970a_write_single(interface, TRF7970A_REG_IO_CTRL, regio);
        trf7970a_write_single(interface, TRF7970A_CHIP_STATUS_CTRL, 0x00);
        trf7970a_command(interface, TRF7970A_CMD_FIFO_RESET);
        trf7970a_write_single(interface, TRF7970A_ADJUTABLE_FIFO_IRQ_LEVELS, 0x0F);
        trf7970a_read_single(interface, TRF7970A_IRQ_STATUS, &regio);
    
    }
```

Comment: You haven't posted your code, so we can't help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Would also really need the code for the MCU and the JavaCard Applet as you need to match up the correct NFC commands as the JavaCard can respond in many different ways.

Comment: Could you try starting with `0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0x09`? The first `0x00` byte in there is the CLASS byte, then comes `0xA4` which means the SELECT INS, see ISO/IEC 7816-4... If there needs to be anything in front of that it's probably the NAD, PCB and length field, see T=1 protocol.

Comment: I have tried starting with     0x00     , like Maarten suggested, and still same problem. I do not get any answer from the card.